# Python PyQt5 Pasar a Gris una imagen cargada

Tags: python, pyqt5, opencv

estoy diseñando una aplicación en la cual cargas una imagen y tambien la puedes eliminar, ademas de eso quiero que cuando opriman otro botón pase la imagen cargada a Gris, estoy usando opencv pero al intentarlo se me cierra la ventana sola, aqui esta el codigo:

el codigo tiene una ventana en la cual hay algunos botones, cree un QLabel en el cual se cargan las imagenes, pero no se como pasarla con el tercer boton la imagen cargada de rgb a gris, lo intente como se muestra en la funcion **BYN** con opencv pero se me cierra y no me da errores, porfavor ayuda.

El Codigo:

```
class VentanaVISUALIZAR(QDialog):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(VentanaVISUALIZAR, self).__init__()

    self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("icono.png"))
    self.setWindowTitle("Visualizador de Radiografias - INICM")
    self.setWindowFlags(Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
    self.setFixedSize(1080, 680)
    
    
    self.widget()
    
          


def widget(self):

    self.labelImagen = QLabel(self)
    self.labelImagen.setGeometry(110, 80, 930, 480)

    self.labelImagen.setStyleSheet("QLabel {background-color: white; border: 1px solid "
                                   "#01DFD7; border-radius: 5px;}")
    self.labelImagen.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)


    botonVCargar = QPushButton(self)
    botonVCargar.setGeometry(QRect(25,95,60,60))
    botonVCargar.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("cargar.png"))
    botonVCargar.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(20,20))
    botonVCargar.setToolTip("Cargar Imagen")

    BoxCargar = QLabel(self)
    BoxCargar.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Sanserif",15))
    BoxCargar.setText("Cargar")
    BoxCargar.move(25,160)
    
    botonVEliminar = QPushButton(self)
    botonVEliminar.setGeometry(QRect(25,220,60,60))
    botonVEliminar.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("borrar.png"))
    botonVEliminar.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(20,20))
    botonVEliminar.setToolTip("Eliminar Imagen")

    BoxEliminar = QLabel(self)
    BoxEliminar.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Sanserif",15))
    BoxEliminar.setText("Eliminar")
    BoxEliminar.move(20,285)

    botonVBYN = QPushButton(self)
    botonVBYN.setGeometry(QRect(25,345,60,60))
    botonVBYN.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("bn.png"))
    botonVBYN.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(20,20))
    botonVBYN.setToolTip("Cambiar a Blanco y Negro")

    BoxBYN = QLabel(self)
    BoxBYN.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Sanserif",15))
    BoxBYN.setText("B & N")
    BoxBYN.move(30,410)
          

    botonVCargar.clicked.connect(self.Cargar)
    botonVEliminar.clicked.connect(lambda: self.labelImagen.clear())
    botonVBYN.clicked.connect(self.BYN)

def Cargar(self):

   imagen, extension = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Seleccionar imagen",
                                                  QDir.currentPath(),
                                                  "Archivos de imagen (*.jpg *.png *.ico *.bmp)")
   if imagen:
        # Adaptar imagen
        pixmapImagen = QPixmap(imagen).scaled(925, 470, Qt.KeepAspectRatio,
                                              Qt.SmoothTransformation)

        # Mostrar imagen
        self.labelImagen.setPixmap(pixmapImagen)


    
def BYN(self):

    
    lambda:self.labelImagen.clear()
    self.labelImagen.setPixmap(gris)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes conseguir el mismo efecto (mostrar una imagen en blanco y negro) mediante `Qt` sin necesidad de Opencv.

```
from PySide2.QtGui import QColor
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QGraphicsColorizeEffect

estilo_gris = QGraphicsColorizeEffect(self)
estilo_gris.setColor(QColor(0, 0, 0))
self.labelImagen.setGraphicsEffect(estilo_gris)
```

Si quisieras eliminar ese efecto de la imagen, más tarde, basta con:

```
self.labelImagen.setGraphicsEffect(None)
```

Comment: Hola, lo probe pero me salio un error:

FIXME Unions cannot be used with isinstance().

La verdad no se que es

Comment: Puede que se deba a algun cambio entre PyQt5 y PySide2. Por lo general suelen ser similares pero hay alguna que otra diferencia.

Comment: Entonces que tendria que hacer en ese caso?

Comment: Sin conocer exactamente el código que estás usando y/o la version de la libreria, solamente con lo que dice el error es imposible saberlo.